# Function such that $f(x) = -1$ for $x < 0,$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x > 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is a function to returns $-1$ if number is negative, $1$ if positive, and zero if number is equal to 0?

for example:

$$
f(-8) = -1
$$
$$
f(8) = 1
$$
$$
f(0) = 0
$$

for $$x < 0$$ maybe?

$$ f(x) = (-x-(-x-1))\cdot-1 $$

Comment: The Heaviside step function almost satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Not exactly. By using it, $$H(-3) = 0,H(3) = 1$$

Comment: The idea, I think, is to use $2H(x) - 1$. But it's a much better idea (IMO) to just say what you mean, like in Trevor's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function is the $\text{sgn}$ (sign) function. You can write it as $$\text{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x{|x|} &x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice, and quick! $\;+ \;\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks very much. What do you think about my first solution too bad or acceptable to a begginer to math? I will to accept your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't give my up vote because I'm < 15 reputation.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your suggestion, because there is no $=$ symbol (you may want to use parenthesis for the $-1$ and `\cdot` for the multiplication). But the problem is that the function is not continuous, so you cannot represent it as a multiplication and addition like that, because that would be continuous. Note that it simplifies to $-(-x+(x+1))=-(x-x+1)=-1$, which is not the function you want.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank you again. And +1 of course

Comment: @Assembly: No problem, and thank you as well!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Is not `sign(-10) = 1`?

Comment: @Assembly: Of course not. Negative numbers get $-1$, not $1$. And $-10<0$.

Comment: Ah,of course. It's because I was doing `y = x/x` instead of `y = x/abs(x)`

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Last question: In your example,you give the equation to show as `x` value should be calculated. While Trevor Wilson's answer,the value that should be returned. How are called? function definition and declaration or something like this?

Comment: @Assembly: I just left you an answer to this question on Trevor's answer! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila:If I increment my thanks-counter to you,an integer overflow may happens. Better say nothing! joke answer. Thank you again.

Comment: ...ok,maybe it's a horrible joke...

Answer (score 12):

As pointed out in the other answers, this function goes by various names.  However, if your question is just "what *is* such a function?" then the answer is that it is the function you have defined.  Note that

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if } x<0\\
1 & \text{if } x>0\\
0 & \text{if } x=0
\end{cases}$$

is a perfectly valid definition of a function on $\mathbb{R}$, because it uniquely specifies what $f(x)$ is for every real number $x$.  Definitions by cases are just as good as any other kind of definition, and I think it is confusing to hide the distinction between the three cases (negative, positive, and zero) by some algebraic trick.

Comment: I have a question. In the Asaf Karagila's answer,he show the function and an equation to how should `x` be computed. In your answer,you show also the result what value of `x` according to condition. How they are this called? function definition and declaration or something like this?

Comment: @Assembly, whereas I presented a slightly more compact form (which lumped the non-zero cases together) that required a small computation, Trevor is using constant functions and simply defined by three cases rather than two cases like myself. This is "definition by cases", and as long the cases are non-overlapping the definition is fine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks again.

Comment: @Assembly Asaf's answer and my answer contain two different definitions of the same function.  The respective definitions also both hint at how the function can be computed.  (Asaf's answer is a bit more complicated than necessary from a computational point of view; there is no need to use division when computing values of the function.)

Comment: (Aside: the cases should be complete as well as non-overlapping! That is to say, you should make sure you don't accidentally specify a value for any particular $x$ twice, and you should make sure you specify at least one value for each $x$.)

Comment: @TrevorWilson: Thanks very much

Answer (score 4):

Your function is *exactly* the [signum function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)